# chef - restart a service on another machine after connecting to it

Tags: amazon-web-services, solr, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm new to chef and struggling with this concept - I'm not sure if it's possible and if it is, how to achieve it.  Thus far Google Fu has failed me.

I have a chef client and chef server, i'm uploading cookbooks to run on my client.  I trigger the code by running chef-client on the chef client machine.

What I'm then trying to do is connect to several other boxes via ssh and then stop a service, clear out a directory and restart the service.

When working I'll be targeting Solr service

My basic test code is as follows:

```
    ruby_block 'do something' do
    block do
        Chef::Log.info('Do Something')
        Chef::Resource::Notification.new('stop', :run, self)
    end
end

#define the service - does nothing
service 'atd' do
    action :nothing
end

#do something that triggers
execute 'start' do
  command 'pwd'
    Chef::Log.info('triggers start')
    action :nothing
    notifies :start, run_context.resource_collection.find(:service => 'atd')
end

execute 'stop' do
    # some stuff
    # on success...
    command 'pwd'
    Chef::Log.info('triggers restart')
    notifies :stop, run_context.resource_collection.find(:service => 'atd'), :immediately
    notifies :run, 'execute[start]'
end
```

in the ruby block I plan on iterating through a list of machines that I have and ssh'ing to them.  Is it then possible to run the remainder of the code on those machines?

Thanks for any help / advice.

Comment: Chef is not the tool for this, there has been talk about managed nodes at a time, but this has been abandoned, best bet would be using something else if you don't want to install chef on those other nodes. something like rundeck or ansible would be a better fit if you're after an agent less management.

Comment: @Tensibai, thanks for the information.  Would it be viable if chef were installed on those machines?

Comment: Chef is a pull model, let chef run periodically and it will bring the machine in line with the desired state defined in the cookbook. (Starting the run from another chef run makes not much sense in this vision)

Comment: You probably want to use Habitat (by Chef) for this functionality.

Comment: @Derek - thanks Derek, I'm now going to investigate this further.